# Custom Accessory View on UITableView Prototype Cell Not Firing

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode-storyboard

I have a custom accessory view (a UIButton) on my prototype cell in a storyboard.  When I click that button the delegate method for accessory button tapped isn't called.  If I use a standard disclosure button it is called just fine.  I'm assuming I'm missing a hook up somewhere.  Anybody know where?

Comment: I'm using a UITableViewCell subclass and designing the cell in interface builder.  I'm not doing it from the table view controller.  I need to call out from that subclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up working around this using a protocol for custom table cells.

CustomAccessoryTableCellDelegate.h

```
@protocol CustomAccessoryTableCellDelegate <NSObject>

     @required
     - (void) accessoryButtonTappedForCell: (UITableViewCell *) cell;

@end
```

CustomAccessoryViewTableCell.h

```
 @interface CustomAccessoryViewTableCell : UITableViewCell

      /** The custom accessory delegate. */
      @property (nonatomic, weak) id<CustomAccessoryTableCellDelegate> delegate;

 @end
```

CustomAccessoryViewTableCell.m

```
- (IBAction) buttonAction:(id)sender{

    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(accessoryButtonTappedForCell:)]) {
        [self.delegate accessoryButtonTappedForCell:self];
    }

}
```

Inside Table View Controller

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    CustomAccessoryViewTableCell *cell = [tableView
                         dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCustomCell"];

    cell.label.text = @"Some Name";
    cell.delegate = self;

    return cell;
 }

#pragma mark - Custom Accessory View Delegate

- (void) accessoryButtonTappedForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell{
    [self tableView:self.writerTable 
        accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: [self.writerTable
                                                      indexPathForCell:cell]];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Guess 1:**
You don't really have a "custom accessory view" you have a `UIButton` which is placed where an accessory would go. This wouldn't fire the delegate accessory tapped button because it's not really an accessory.

**Guess 2:**
You do have a real accessory view, but it's never getting the "tap" event because you have a `UIButton` in it which is eating the user interaction but not firing an action. In that case try adding a simple `UIView` instead.

Other than that, I'd need more information.

Comment: I tried using an image view instead which didn't make any difference. The button is hooked up to the UITableViewCell's accessoryView property.  Is there not a way to programmatically call this from a UITableViewCell subclass?

Comment: In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, after you get the cell, check to see if your `accessoryView` property has a reference to your view or if it's `nil`. If it's setup correctly in IB, it should exist.

Comment: I shows the button/view/whatever I have there.  Seems like it only handles the tap event on it's own defined accessory view types.  And there doesn't seem to be a good way to do it programmatically from the table cell.  I ended up using a custom protocol, which I'll put in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

apple docs for the accessory delegate method says

> The delegate usually responds to the tap on the disclosure button (the accessory view) by displaying a new view related to the selected row. This method is not called when an accessory view is set for the row at indexPath.

so it is not called for custom accessory views. it is a standard behaviour.